# How can I download a yt video by opening a file save dialog?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ytdl

I'm trying to make a yt video downloader as a website, and i want to prompt the user on where to save the video to be downloaded, just like how we download a resource from a website normally.

i'm trying to find js libraries to work with. As of now i have tried ytdl-core, although it doesn't open up a prompt for me. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: you must pipe `ytdl` to a file on your server; then, send tothe  browser a response containing the appropriate link